# Try block do not handle scenario when element not found

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, try-catch, webdriverwait

I used  below code and found that TRY block is not working for the situation when element is not present :

```
try
{      
    var actual = new WebDriverWait(m_WebDriver, TimeSpan
        .FromSeconds(5))
        .Until(ExpectedConditions
        .ElementIsVisible(By.XPath(XpathUnderTest)))
        .Displayed;

    return actual;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{      
   return false;
}
```

I have a use-case where presence of Webelement is depend on other conditions so it is not present or visible all the time on webpage. If element is present then it's working and if element is not present then Try catch is not able to handle the scenario using you above code.

I also tried : bool isPresent = Driver.Findelements.(xpath).Count() > 0; // list 
but it is not working as well if element is not present

Comment: What do you mean "is not able to handle the scenario" ? Do you get an error?

Comment: yes I get failure message : openqa.selenium.webdriverexception The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver timed out after 60 seconds.   Somehow I got the trace log which syas code is able to go into Catch block but then again I am not sure why it got stuck there. why driver was not able to move on ?

Comment: Please share the code where you call this function. Since you said the catch block was processed, then the problem is probably occurring after it returns false. What are you doing after getting false back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your code block it's the right behavior as **`WebDriverWait`** with **`ElementIsVisible`** is correct.

As per the [**`documentation`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_ElementIsVisible.htm), **`ExpectedConditions`** with **`ElementIsVisible`** will return the **`IWebElement`** once it is located and visible. In case the **`ExpectedConditions`** fails a **`Boolean`** value is returned back.

As in your `try` block you are defining :

```
var actual;
```

And trying to :

```
return actual;
```

So, irespective of the return from **`ExpectedConditions`** with **`ElementIsVisible`** your **`try`** block returns [**`False Positive`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_positives_and_false_negatives).

### Solution :

**`WebDriverWait`** with **`ExpectedConditions`** must be implemented outside any **`Try-Catch`** block. Next steps can be decided with respect to the return type.

Comment: yes , I defined 'WebDriverWait ' outside and I have been validating lots of stuff outside of actual test logic.